# How can I resolve "HTTP Error 500.19 error code 0x8007000d - Internal Server Error"?

Tags: iis, tomcat, 500-error, html, javascript

I'm currently trying to redirect errors on my Tomcat project.

Currently I'm using this method of redirecting the errors by using **httpsError** in the **web.config file**. Here is the code and error that I got. `HTTP Error 500.19, error code 0x8007000d` And I have URL Rewrite installed.

Sorry for the horrible images, I wasn't able to take a snippet. I know there are other solutions for Tomcat (for some reason it doesn't work) thus I am using **web.config** instead and this is the closest to success.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0WGd.jpg)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLwT4.jpg)

Comment: Please provide your config file as *text*, and the error message either as text or as an readable screenshot.

Comment: If you cannot provide the complete `applicationHost.config` file, it is impossible for anyone to confirm what's wrong there. A screenshot is far from enough. One tip you might try is to open this file in an editor like Notepad++ and enable display of all hidden characters. That often reveals corruption you neglect in a glance.